# Unable to sort a MAP in clojure on the basis of nested fields

Tags: clojure

I am trying to sort the below map( Clojure) on the basis of "col_nm" field, but unable to do so.

```
{:Mawb {:user_val "3", :col_nm "1"}, 
 :HawbDate {:user_val "", :col_nm "3"}, 
 :EtlBatchID {:user_val "1", :col_nm "2"}}
```

The output should be:

```
{:Mawb {:user_val "3", :col_nm "1"}, 
 :EtlBatchID {:user_val "1", :col_nm "2"}, 
 :HawbDate {:user_val "", :col_nm "3"} }
```

Can anyone help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maps in clojure do not have order, except for the ones created by `sorted-map` and even those are only sorted on keys, not on values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(def m {:Mawb {:user_val "3", :col_nm "1"},
        :HawbDate {:user_val "", :col_nm "3"},
        :EtlBatchID {:user_val "1", :col_nm "2"}})

(sort-by (comp :col_nm second) m)
=> ([:Mawb {:user_val "3", :col_nm "1"}]
    [:EtlBatchID {:user_val "1", :col_nm "2"}]
    [:HawbDate {:user_val "", :col_nm "3"}])
```

Comment: Works perfectly!!
One more query other than sorting-
is there an inbuilt function or a short way to remove the ones on the basis of condition on the nested ones. For example for this map

{:Mawb {:user_val "3", :col_nm "1"}, 
 :HawbDate {:user_val "", :col_nm "3"}, 
 :EtlBatchID {:user_val "1", :col_nm ""}}

if "col_nm" field is blank the output should be

{:Mawb {:user_val "3", :col_nm "1"}, 
 :HawbDate {:user_val "", :col_nm "3"}
 }

Comment: @Avi `(filter (comp pos? count :col_nm second) m)`

Comment: `(comp pos? count)` is just an inefficient way to write `seq` (when used as a predicate).