# Sort nested map Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to sort a map by a key value. Given this map:

```
{:1 {:bar "something" :rank 10} :2 {:bar "other" :rank 20}}
```

I like to sort it by `rank` value:

```
{:2 {:bar "other" :rank 20} :1 {:bar "something" :rank 10} }
```

Its possible using `sort-by` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sort-by takes a key function as well as an optional custom comparator

```
;              keyfn         comparator
(sort-by (comp :rank second) > 
  {:1 {:bar "something" :rank 10} :2 {:bar "other" :rank 20}})
;=> ([:2 {:bar "other", :rank 20}] [:1 {:bar "something", :rank 10}])
```

Comment: How would you do this with `(get)` instead of `:rank`? For example, a string is the keyname.

Comment: @triplej since `:rank` is used where a `fn` can be used, any `fn` can be used: i.e. `(comp #(get % "foo") second)` - the fact that keywords can be used has nothing to do with `sort-by` but with how `Maps` work, i.e. `(:foo a-map)` will work `("foo" a-map)` won't. - (for completes sake `Maps` are lookups to themself, so `(a-map :foo)` will also work)

Answer (score 3):

It's simple enough to do with `sort-by`, but since that sorts in ascending order, you'll have to use `reverse` to get it to go the right way.

```
(reverse
    (sort-by (comp :rank second)
        {:1 {:bar "something" :rank 10} :2 {:bar "other" :rank 20}}))
```

Comment: this doesn't work. add another element with rank 15 as element 3 and you'll see it's not sorted, you've only got 10 and 20 that by chance are ordering how you want them

Comment: Yeah, I was just playing around with it again.  It seems to be sorting lexicographically which isn't what I want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too. Nice to know about it too.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers will work, but if you are going to be doing this command a lot, then you would be better off storing the data in a [data.priority-map](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map). It is designed for situations just like this.

> A priority map is very similar to a sorted map, but whereas a sorted map produces a sequence of the entries sorted by key, a priority map produces the entries sorted by value.

```clj
; You'll need to add [org.clojure/data.priority-map "0.0.7"] to :dependencies first

user=> (require '[clojure.data.priority-map :as pm])
; nil
user=> (pm/priority-map-keyfn-by :rank > 
         :1 {:bar "something" :rank 10}
         :2 {:bar "other" :rank 20})
; {:2 {:rank 20, :bar "other"}, :1 {:rank 10, :bar "something"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122065/unable-to-sort-a-map-in-clojure-on-the-basis-of-nested-fields)

Ascending:

```
user=> (sort-by (comp :rank second) < {:1 {:bar "something" :rank 10} :2 {:bar "other" :rank 20} :3 {:bar "bar" :rank 15}})
([:1 {:bar "something", :rank 10}] [:3 {:bar "bar", :rank 15}] [:2 {:bar "other", :rank 20}])
```

Descending:

```
user=> (sort-by (comp :rank second) > {:1 {:bar "something" :rank 10} :2 {:bar "other" :rank 20} :3 {:bar "bar" :rank 15}})
([:2 {:bar "other", :rank 20}] [:3 {:bar "bar", :rank 15}] [:1 {:bar "something", :rank 10}])
```

These both return the sequence of elements of map, to convert back to a map again, wrap it in `(into {} ...)`