# How do I use sort-by on nested maps when the keys are strings, not keywords?

Tags: sorting, clojure, hashmap

[Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697459/sort-nested-map-clojure)

This works with keywords

```
(sort-by (comp :rank second) > 
  {:1 {:bar "something" :rank 10} :2 {:bar "other" :rank 20}})
```

This fails when it's a string

```
(sort-by (comp "rank" second) >
  {:1 {:bar "something" "rank" 10} :2 {:bar "other" "rank" 20}})
```

Error message is "Execution error (ClassCastException) at java.util.TimSort/countRunAndMakeAscending (TimSort.java:355).
java.lang.String incompatible with clojure.lang.IFn"

I take it the problem is that keywords can be a function but strings cannot be functions. What is the solution? I've tried playing around with `get` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`comp` composes functions, so you'll need a function that can get the key by string:

```
user> (->> {:1 {:bar "something" "rank" 10} :2 {:bar "other" "rank" 20}}
           (sort-by (comp #(get % "rank") second) >))
([:2 {:bar "other", "rank" 20}] [:1 {:bar "something", "rank" 10}])
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(comp :rank second)` is the same as writing `(fn [x] (:rank (second x)))`.

Similarly, `(comp :rank "second")` would be `(fn [x] (:rank ("second" x)))`, but `"second"`  is a String. It cannot be invoked like a function.

Use a function instead, like `#(get % "second")` or just `#(% "second")`.

Answer (score 0):

In Clojure, a keyword can act as a function, so it works with `comp`. A `String` does not have this special status.  The easiest way is to make a dedicated function to extract the sort key. Here is one way with unit tests:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn nested-rank
  [me]
  (get (second me) "rank"))

(verify
  ; when iterating over a map, each map-entry looks like a 2-elem vector
  (is= 10 (nested-rank [:1 {:bar "something" "rank" 10}]))

  (let [data {:1 {:bar "something" "rank" 10}
              :2 {:bar "other" "rank" 20}}]
    (is= (sort-by nested-rank > data)
      [[:2 {:bar "other" "rank" 20}]
       [:1 {:bar "something" "rank" 10}]])))
```

build using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).